# Prove that if every root of $P(x)$ is real then every root of $P'(x),P''(x),.. $are real too

Tags: real-analysis

I think this is not so difficult a question.

I want to make sure what I did is correct.

First take two immediate roots of $P(x)$, then there is a point $x_0$ such that $P'(x_0)$ is zero. This exactly is a solution and between every immediate roots, there is one such $x_n$. Since all roots of $P(x)$ lie in real plane, the points $x_n$ also lie in real plane.

This continues in the same pattern for $P^n(x)$

Is this correct?

Comment: is this $P$ a polynomial?

Comment: ...and if they coincide, the derivative has a root at that point.

Comment: yes. sorry missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the added subtlety that if $P$ has degree $n$, and therefore $n$ real roots then there are $n-1$ of these intermediate critical points which coincide with the degree of $P'$ being $n-1$. Without this argument there is nothing to say that $P'$ doesn't have roots other than those described. Other than this you are spot on.

Comment: There's a bit more subtlety than that.  If $P$ has degree $n$ there may be fewer than $n$ **distinct** real roots.  However, if $r$ is a root of $P$ of multiplicity $m > 1$, then it is a root of $P'$ of multiplicity $m-1$, so the count still comes out OK.