# The polynomial $P(x)=x^4 -\sqrt{7} x^3 + 4x^2 - \sqrt{22} x+15$ has four different roots. Prove that not all zeros of polynomial $P(x)$ are real

Tags: real-analysis, roots

This is from my real analysis class. I know how to show a function has exactly one root but im not sure how to go about this.

Comment: Maybe this would be cheating, but using [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290175/prove-that-if-every-root-of-px-is-real-then-every-root-of-px-px?rq=1) as a lemma, consider $P''(x)$ and use the quadratic formula. (You should get $D = b^2 - 4ac = -132$.)

Answer (score 8):

One way to do this is to use the relationship between the roots and coefficients of a polynomial. If the roots are $a, b, c, d$, then $\sqrt{7} = a+b+c+d$ and $4 = ab+bc+cd+ac+bd+ad$. Then $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 = (a+b+c+d)^2 - 2(ab+bc+cd+ac+bd+ad) = 7 - 8 = -1$, which is a problem if the roots are all real.

Comment: (+1) although this does come across as "magic" to me. What would be a general method to show that not all roots are real?

Comment: As far as I know, any completely general methods for doing this require a good bit of linear algebra machinery.

Answer (score 3):

This is a standard application of Rolle's theorem.

Assume by contradiction that $P(x)$ has $4$ distinct real roots. Let the roots be $a< b < c <  d$. Then by Rolle, $P'$ has at least three roots $e \in (a,b), f \in (b,c), g \in (c,d)$ and hence $e<f<g$.

Again, by Rolle applied to $P'$, $P''$ has at least two real roots, $h \in (e,f), i \in (f,g)$.

But $P''(x)=12x^2-6\sqrt{7}x+8$ has no real roots, contradiction.

**P.S.** By this method you can prove the following more general result: if the $n$th derivative $f^{(n)}$ has at most $m$ real roots then $f$ has at most $n+m$ real roots [not counting multiplicity].